# 1772 of Caribbean online judge giving a time limit exceeded error. please help me find why is my algorithm taking so long

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, analysis

So I am trying to solve the problem 1772 of the Caribbean online judge web page http://coj.uci.cu/24h/problem.xhtml?abb=1772, the problem asks to find if a substring of a bigger string contains at least one palindrome inside it:

e.g. Analyzing the sub-strings taken from the following string: "baraabarbabartaarabcde"

"bara" contains a palindrome "ara"

"abar" contains a palindrome "aba"

"babar" contains a palindrome "babar"

"taar" contains a palindrome "aa"

"abcde" does not contains any palindrome.

etc etc etc...

I believe my approach is really fast because I am iterating the strings starting at the first char and at the last char at the same time, advancing towards the center of the string looking only for the following patterns: "aa" "aba" whenever I find a pattern like those I can say the substring given contains a palindrome inside it. Now the problem is that the algorithm is taking a long time but I can't spot the problem on it. Please help me find it I am really lost on this one. Here is my algorithm

```
public static boolean hasPalindromeInside(String str)
{
    int midpoint=(int) Math.ceil((float)str.length()/2.0);
    int k = str.length()-1;

    for(int i = 0; i < midpoint;i++)
    {
        char letterLeft = str.charAt(i);
        char secondLetterLeft=str.charAt(i+1);
        char letterRight = str.charAt(k);
        char secondLetterRight =  str.charAt(k-1);

        if((i+2)<str.length())
        {
            char thirdLetterLeft=str.charAt(i+2);
            char thirdLetterRight=str.charAt(k-2);


            if(letterLeft == thirdLetterLeft || letterRight == thirdLetterRight)
            {
                return true;
            }

        }


        if(letterLeft == secondLetterLeft || letterRight==secondLetterRight)
        {
            return true;
        }

    k--;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

I have removed the code that grabs the input strings and intervals of sub-strings, I am using String.substring() to get the substrings and I don't think that will be causing the problem. If you need that code please let me know.
 Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that a fast solution would not treat each substring separately.

Comment: So creating a hash map with ranges of where the palindromes are and then just searching to see if the given ranges have one right? That would stop the program from repeatedly searching the same string for palindromes, thanks Patricia that might work really fast.

Comment: I have not worked out how to use the fact that all the substrings are substrings of the same string - if I had, I would have posted an answer. I'm just suggesting that as a line of thinking. Be careful with hash maps - they can have good expected performance, but bad worst case performance.

Comment: Perhaps another approach would be to find all the palindromes in the bigger string and just check if the range has any palindrome range inside. That way, you won't have to find for a palindrome in overlapping ranges

Comment: @JuanGuerrero has the right approach.  Find all the 2 and 3 character palindromes and save them in a data structure that makes it quick to determine if an interval contains at least one of them.

Comment: This won't work for any kind of input anyways. It's not generalized to include longer palindromes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this in O(1) time per query given O(n) preprocessing to find the locations of all 2 and 3 character palindromes.  (Any even plaindrome will have a 2 character plaindrome at the centre, while any odd will have a 3 character one so it suffices to check 2 and 3.)

For example,

Given your string baraabarbabartaarabcde, first compute an array indicating the locations of the 2 character palindromes:

```
baraabarbabartaarabcde
000100000000001000000-
```

Then compute the cumulative sum of this array:

```
baraabarbabartaarabcde
000100000000001000000-
000111111111112222222-
```

By doing a subtraction you can immediately work out whether there are any 2 character palindromes in a query range.

Similarly for three character plaindromes:

```
baraabarbabartaarabcde  String
01001000100000010000--  Indicator
01112222333333344444--  Cumulative
```

Comment: Please explain "by doing a subtraction".

Comment: For "taar" C[15]=2 means there are 2 2-digit palindromes starting at or before character 15, and C[12]=1 means there is 1 2-digit palindrome starting at or before character 12, so we can deduce that there must be C[15]-C[12]=2-1=1 2-digit palindrome in the substring of characters from 13 to 16 (i.e. 'taar' contains a plaindrome)

Comment: Loved this approach, I've only one concern but I think it can be solved rather easily: what would happen with an interval that begins at C[14] & ends at C[15] (watch 2 letters array), the algorithm would see the digits C[14]=1 and C[15]=2 making it think that in that interval there is a palindrome when the interval is just the letters "ta" what I can add to your solution is to mark the ending of every palindrome instead of the beginning, this way only when the interval checked contains a complete palindrome the difference in the cumulative sums will be noticeable through a subtraction.

Comment: You're right @AngelDurán, you actually use start-1 and end-2 (or end-3 for the threes) for checking (where start is the starting element of the query interval and end is the end of the query interval) - I just got it working at COJ. (Also, of course you can't subtract 1 from start if it's a 0, so in that case that the interval starts at 0 you just check for non zero on the 0th position). But otherwise the basic idea is very cool - thanks PeterDeRivas